# PLSQL Update based on value in another field (using conditionals)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is psuedo code for what I am trying to accomplish

I have 2 fields: salary and region, and I have USD to region conversions

If the salary is not null, then I want to multiply the salary by the USD to region conversion based on the Region

Here is the psuedo code:

```
if region = 'r 1' then 
   update table
   set salary = nvl2(salary, salary * 1.58, null)
else if region = 'r 2' then
   update table
   set salary = nvl2(salary, salary * 1.13, null)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What *specifically* do you need help with?

Comment: is the structure correct?  Do I need to put begin and end around it?

Comment: It's hard to tell from pseudo-code. Is this supposed to be an anonymous PL/SQL block, a stored procedure, ...? Do you really need PL/SQL?  Could you not simply do a simple update?  Where does `region` come from?  From your text description, it appears to be a field from your table, but from the pseudo-code, it seems to be perhaps some PL/SQL variable.  You might have to add more specific details.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way:

```
update table
set salary = salary * 1.58
where region = 'r 1' and salary is not null;

update table
set salary = salary * 1.13
where region = 'r 2' and salary is not null;
```

In one step with [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

```
update table
set salary = case 
              when region = 'r 1'
                then salary * 1.58
              when region = 'r 2'
                then salary * 1.13
            end
where salary is not null
and region in ('r 1', 'r 2');
```

With Oracle [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function:

```
update table
set salary =  salary * DECODE(supplier_id, 'r 1', 1.58,
                                           'r 2', 1.13)
where salary is not null
and region in ('r 1', 'r 2') ;
```

Comment: First one may be is the best, index friendly, no full table scan needed.

Comment: You need the condition `and region in ('r 1', 'r 2')` for the second and third query otherwise the salary for all other regions will be set to `null`.

Comment: Nice! @a_horse_with_no_name, I will fix it!